# Filtering source code in Maven

Tags: maven-2, filtering

I wrote a small BeanShell script that replaces `"__LINE__"` with the actual line number in source code. It works well in Ant.

I am looking for a way to filter source code in Maven so that my BeanShell script can generate a new source code directory that then gets compiled.

I know about resource file filtering. Is there any similar facility for source code?

Answer (score 26):

Filtering source code was still tricky some months ago, but there's now a standard plugin at the MOJO project. You can now do that with a classic plugin declaration.

To filter source code (for example, when you'd like to have a constant in your Java code to retrieve the project version or artifactId), you should now use the [templating-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/).

1. Put your code that should be filtered during the build under `src/main/java-templates` as you would normally do under `src/main/java` for non filtered sources. Use `${project.version}` or whatever property coming from the POM in your code.
2. Just put something like:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-alpha-3</version> <!-- Be sure to use the last version. Check on the website's plugin -->
     <executions>
         <execution>
         <id>filter-src</id>
         <goals>
             <goal>filter-sources</goal>
         </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Be done :-). The code you put inside `src/main/java-templates` gets filtered and added to the classpath.

The usage is very straightforward (see the [example here](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/examples/source-filtering.html)).

This respects far better the idea of convention over configuration of Maven. You're basically replacing tens of XML lines and some hacks to get something done cleanly.

Side note: this works fine with Eclipse for example.

Comment: Hi, I tried following your answer above, but when I import the project into eclipse-kepler and enable eclipse's auto-build, its complaining that it cannot find the classes in `src/main/java-templates` src dir...also looking at the project source build path, the `src/main/java-templates` src dir is not there...not sure if it should be there. Just to also mention that the project builds successfully when I run `mvn install` from eclipse, but I want eclipse not to complain about and it should automatically pick processed source from `target/generated-sources/java-templates` or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: src/main/java-templates isn't a source folder, and must not be configured as one inside the IDE. Doing this will clash with the target/generated-sources/java-templates filtered directory (which has to show as a source folder in Eclipse, which you shouldn't edit).

Comment: For the automatic refresh inside Eclipse, I think you're missing some M2E configuration, try adding https://gist.github.com/Batmat/9529785 in your pom.xml. Does it work better?

Comment: I use the build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source goal so Eclipse will add the source directory to the project when updating the project using maven.   configuration/sources/source = ${project.build.directory}/generate-sources/java-templates

Comment: @AaronRoller bad idea: doing that, you actually add that folder to the classpath twice. The templating-maven-plugin already does it. It's just that it must be configured to run in Eclipse through M2E too.