# Is there a way to use maven property in Java class during compilation

Tags: java, maven, compilation

I just want to use maven placeholder in my Java class at compile time in order to reduce duplication.

Something like that:

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
  <some.version>1.0</some.version>
</properties>
```

**SomeVersion.java**

```
package some.company;

public class SomeVersion {

    public static String getVersion() {
        return "${some.version}"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

simply create file app.properties in src/main/resources with content like this

```
application.version=${project.version}
```

then enable maven filtering like this

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

That's all - in app code just read properties file

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource( "app.properties" );
p = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    p.load( inputStream );
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    LOGGER.error( e.getMessage(), e );
} finally {
    Closeables.closeQuietly( inputStream );
}
```

and provide method like this

```
public static String projectVersion() {
    return p.getProperty( "application.version" );
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is definitely better than feeding the source code through a preprocessor.

Comment: Isn't `ClassPathResource` spring-specific? OP did not include the `spring` tag.

Comment: This approach, in my own view, is better than the uses of **properties-maven-plugin** (It works too) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589696/3072683)

Comment: The property in my case is returning value as ${project.version}

Also I have to files in my resource folder but I am reading only one of them in which is i have written version=${project.version}

Comment: Just for the heads up ClassPathResource works with spring only. If you want to implement this logic in plain java it won't work

Comment: @NitishKumar maybe you get this cause you skipped the pom file part (setting the file in to be filtered). @fegemo you can do it with simple java with `getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties")`

Comment: This might actually be a dangerous thing if using build pipelines because your files will always change on remote repositories, creating conflicts later one when pushing changes

Comment: In my code I already write one resource ein webresource tag, when I tried to add another resource with your code it gives me error, do you know any solution?

Answer (score 10):

Even though it's not a very nice solution it is possible with the default maven resource plugin.

First you need to specify the resource plugin.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <!-- Configure the source files as resources to be filtered
      into a custom target directory -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>../filtered-sources/java</targetPath>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

Afterwards you will need to change the 'default' configuration of the compiler plugin.

```
<project>
  <build>
      <!-- Overrule the default pom source directory to match
            our generated sources so the compiler will pick them up -->
      <sourceDirectory>target/filtered-sources/java</sourceDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I agree it's not the best or perhaps the most proper way of doing it, but it is *a* way of doing it.

Comment: @Jeroen yes, I agree with you. I can't reproduce that way, but it makes my knowledge wider. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: To do this, use the templating-maven-plugin. It does some of the things included in the maven-resources-plugin, but without the burden of writing tens of XML lines. See http://mojo.codehaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/ and my answer on another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18452939/345845

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I know of doing that is to use [Templating Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/index.html).

Add plugin declaration to your pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>filter-src</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>filter-sources</goal><!-- add this if you filter main sources -->
                <goal>filter-test-sources</goal><!-- add this if you filter test sources -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you're filtering main sources:

- Create folder `src/main/java-templates`
- Move the source files you want to be filtered to that folder. Reproduce package tree structure, as if you were in `src/main`.

If you're filtering tests sources too:

- Create folder `src/test/java-templates`
- Move the source files you want to be filtered to that folder. Reproduce package tree structure, as if you were in `src/test`.

Assuming that your sources contain valid placeholders like:

```
package some.company;

public class SomeVersion {

    public static String getVersion() {
        return "${project.version}"
    }

}
```

Now when you `compile` or `test` your project, those placeholders should be already valued.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Spring, you can inject a property. The steps are:

1. Inside POM file you define all profiles needed and each profile must have your custom property, in your case

```html
<profile>
 <id>dev</id>
 <properties>
  <some.version>Dev Value</some.version>
 </properties>
</profile>
```

2. In the section build of your profile, you define the filtering injection.
3. Under the your project resources directory, you create a properties file (any mnemonic christian name) and put your prop to be injected:

> custom.some.version=${some.version}

4. On the spring-context file you define the properties placeholder and define your bean or beanProperty:

```html
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/META-INF/*.properties"/>
...
<bean id="customConfig" class="com.brand.CustomConfig">
 <property name="someVersion" value="${custom.some.version}" />
</bean>
...
```

5. Create your class.

> ```
> package com.brand;
>
> public class CustomConfig {
>   private String someVersion;
>
>   public getSomeVersion() {
>   return this.someVersion;
>   }
>
>   public setSomeVersion(String someVersion) {
>   this.someVersion = someVersion;
>   }
> }
> ```

6. Inject where you want to use. This example is with autowired bean, but you can use and autowired property too.

> ```
> package com.brand.sub
>
> public class YourLogicClass {
>   @Autowired
>   private CustomConfig customConfig;
>
>   // ... your code
> }
> ```

On the final compilation, you have the correct values.