# How to pass String value to java from cmd (maven project)?

Tags: java, maven

I need to pass String value (jbehave story file name) to .java file from cmd. Something like this:

```
mvn verify -PMyTests -DstoryName=purchasing.story
```

To use in java in that way:

```
System.out.println(storyName);
```

**My setup:**

Now tests being launched by

```
mvn verify -PMyTests
```

**pom.xml** file structure:

```
...
<dependencies>
    ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    ...
<build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>MyTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                ...
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

**MyStories.java**:

```
public class MyStories extends JUnitStories {
    ...
    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder()
            .findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass).getFile(), asList(
                    "**/purchasing.story"
                    ), null);
    }
}
```

Tried these topics: [Is there a way to use maven property in java class during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740618/is-there-a-way-to-use-maven-property-in-java-class-during-compilation), [How to pass java code a parameter from maven for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245411/pass-a-java-parameter-from-maven-for-testng), but with no result. 
Straightforward tutorials, search tips or documentation with examples appreciated.

**P.S.** Found solution which is simple enough and works for me: http://syntx.co/languages-frameworks/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-junit-tests-from-the-maven-surefire-plugin/

Solution provided in comments (topic which I "duplicated") is more complex than this one so it is easier for novice to make mistake implementing it

Comment: You need to include your Java code as well.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245411/pass-a-java-parameter-from-maven-for-testng

Comment: I'm still not quite sure, or convinced that this is a duplicate. The link you've pointed to shows how to run a different group of tests via a test provider in surefire. How is this exactly related? Please, kindly explain, as I fail to understand how five people voted for "close as duplicate". Perhaps I'm not seeing something.

Comment: I think you are right. I used these original topic before creating my own (unsuccessfully) as I wasn't experienced enough to fit it for my needs. 
Also original topic uses annotations and imports in java and also it has more complicated pom.xml which I don't need.

Comment: Sure it was my mistake as I wasn't clear enough in my topic/topics title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the System property like this:

```
public class MyStories extends JUnitStories {
    ...
    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        String storyName = System.getProperty("storyName");
        return new StoryFinder()
            .findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass).getFile(),
                       asList("**/" + storyName),
                       null);
    }
}
```