# Can't read Maven properties

Tags: java, maven, properties

I tried using properties in Maven following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740618/is-there-a-way-to-use-maven-property-in-java-class-during-compilation)

I've created a property:

```
<properties>
    <application.root.url>http://localhost:8080</application.root.url>
</properties>
```

added resource and filtering:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

put the "test.properties" file in src/test/resources directory with the following:

```
application.root.url=${project.application.root.url}
```

In Java, I have this:

```
public static Properties getProperties(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("test.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e){
        props = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return props;
}
```

Now, if I have `new FileInputStream("test.properties")`, I get "file not found" exception, and if I put `new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/test.properties")`, then it returns `${application.root.url}` as a value for the property `application.root.url`

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE 1:**
OK, now I've changed 
`${project.application.root.url}` to

`${application.root.url}`

and

`props.load(new FileInputStream("test.properties"));` to

`props.load(Util.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties"));`

Now I don't get 'file not found' errors any more. But I still have problem that in `target/test-classes/test.properties` value is not changed from `${application.root.url}` (and in `target/classes/test.properties` *it is* changed...)

---

**FINAL UPDATE:**

And finally, everything got to work when I changed 'resources' to 'testResoruces':

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: what happens if you move properites file to main source root instead of test ? i mean move test.properties to /src/main/resources

Comment: Tried that. Even with `src\test\resources` file gets copied to `target\classes` directory, but it could not be found. I also have the same file (but with ${application.root.url} not changed) in `target\test-classes`, but still getting 'file not found' exception....

Comment: `<testResources>
 <testResource>
  <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
 </testResource>
</testResources>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
${project.application.root.url}
```

to

```
${application.root.url}
```

Comment: This helps. The file `target\classes\test.properties` now has appropriate value, but I still can't read it...

Comment: Aaand - the file in `target/test-classes` doesn't have this value changed, and I guess I need that file, since I'm trying to use parameter in test (I want to create profiles for Selenium to target local or staging server).

Comment: From tests `classes` is visible.

Comment: add to <Build> this <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory><filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>