# how to update a property file using maven or pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have created an automation framework where I am reading values from a property file say "config.properties".

My config.propertioes file contains following :

```
BrowserName=${browser}
Environment=${env}
```

I am reading browser value from the property file and passing it to my selenium script to run it.

Now I wants to replace "`${browser}"` && "`${env}"` with value "`ie`"  &&  "`IT"` using pom.xml. Is there any way/plugin using which I can edit a property file using pom.xml.

Please suggest.

@Keshava
I am putting whole example below as suggested below :
1.Have 2 property files: ◦project.properties: This is the file that we commit in the repository. It consists data as follows: ◾project.connection.username=@@DB_USERNAME@@
project.connection.password=@@DB_PASSWORD@@

◦build.properties: This is the file that we do not commit in the repository and is maintained at each of the deployment environments, be it the developers env., UAT env or Production env. The contents of this file are as follows: ◾db.username=mydbuser
db.password=mydbpassword

2.In the project’s pom.xml add the following plugin and a execution:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>replaceTokens</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>target/classes/project.properties</file>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@@DB_USERNAME@@</token>
                            <value>${db.username}</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>@@DB_PASSWORD@@</token>
                            <value>${db.password}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

from above, I understand that `"@@DB_USERNAME@@"` is from `"project.properties"`. But, from which properties file this `"${db.username}"` value will be taken?. how my pom will understand from where to take `"${db.username}"` .

Do I need to pass this value in maven goal like below :

```
mvn clean install -Ddb.username=myuserid
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740618/is-there-a-way-to-use-maven-property-in-java-class-during-compilation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use maven property in Java class during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740618/is-there-a-way-to-use-maven-property-in-java-class-during-compilation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could tryin using the maven replacer plugin
See https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

See an example [here](https://crushedbeans.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/using-maver-replacer-plugin-to-replace-strings-from-a-properties-file/)

Comment: Below is the whole example here : as suggested above :

Comment: please suggest on my above question section I have pasted whole solution in my question section

Comment: in above example how to pass `"${db.password}"` this argument to pom ?

Comment: please help if anyone knows

Answer (score 5):

Hello you can use the [maven resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

This plugin implement "[Maven Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/)".

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>selenium-profile-chrome</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/selenium</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

maven also has a resolvable, inheritable, and also overrideable  section in its nature. You can implement any possible solution using maven profiles together. Your keywords to search for could be "managing maven properties using maven profiles"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).