# How to update environment value in property file using pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, bdd

I have configuration.properties in configs/Configuration.properties where I have url path = http://finacial/dev3/api 
http:// financial/{env}/api
I want to load the environment value from the pom.xml to replace dev 3 according to the environment property set in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filter option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) of the maven [resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html), it does exactly that.

> Variables can be included in your resources. These variables, denoted by the ${...} delimiters, can come from the system properties, your project properties, from your filter resources and from the command line.

E.g. if you have a property `url` in your pom

```
<properties>
     <url>abc</ulr>  
</properties>
```

and your .properties file contains a value `${url}` and you include the file in the resource section of the pom, then `${url}` will be replaced in the output file in the build target location by `abc` upon issuing `mvn resources:resources`

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Comment: I have my urlPath specified in the configs/configuration.properties where it contains environment. http://financial/dev3/api, I have changed it to http://financial/{env}/api. And in pom.xml I have <properties> <envrionment>dev3</environment>. I want this env value to be updated in my urlPath

Comment: So it is not at all in the project directory and not covered in the build? If it is you should be fine by adding it the way `src/main/resources` was added in the example.

Comment: No. It is not. I need it to run my BDD script. I edit the environment to refer to the particular env for testing, When I run my BDD script I want other config files also to use the env specified in pom.xml

Comment: It is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259808/how-to-update-a-property-file-using-maven-or-pom-xml but I have my properties file like urlPath=http://financial/dev/api

Comment: Can't really comment on that. I found this [replacer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157779/maven-replacer-plugin-and-multiple-files), otherwise you can run any ant-command with the [antrun](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin, they have all kind of [replace stuff](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html).