# Create two profiles and use them in Java class

Tags: maven

How can use two Maven profiles with for example `<id = env>`that will contain `id`, `password`, `account#` that will pass those values into `.java` class and in Maven command line I just run something like:

```
mvn test ${env=stage}
```

and it will take `id`, `password`, `account#` from profile that I choose. Or may be there are other way to do that not using profiles?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can declare [`properties`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) in Maven. You can set them in different ways:

- Command line:

  ```
  mvn ... -DmyProperty=myValue
  ```
- In a `<properties>` section in a POM or in `settings.xml` (in the latter in a `<profile>` section only) like:

  ```
  <profile>
    <id>stage</id>

    <properties>
      <user>you</user>
      <password>your</password>
      <accountNo>42</accountNo> 
    </properties>
  <profile>
  ```

Activate profiles on the command line with:

```
mvn ... -Pstage ...
```

or use one of the other activation mechanisms described in the doc [Maven, Introduction to Build Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Use properties in your POM with `${user}`, `${password}`, `${accountNo}`.

Comment: `Use properties in your POM with ${user}, ${password}, ${accountNo}.`           How can I use those values in my .java class after that. Should be something like that :  `String id = ${user} `  or this id I should put in properties file and then in java class call for it?

Comment: @IlyaG It depends on whether you want/need it hardcoded in your class or in an external properties file. The latter is the usual. There is a mechanism in Maven called [_Resource Filtering_](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) (A bad name, IMHO, because with a filter you sort something out. _Resource Interpolation_ would be more appropriate.) See also [Filtering source code in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106171/filtering-source-code-in-maven).