# m2e connector buildhelper not compatible with Eclipse Juno SR1 m2e 1.2

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

**Update**: moved the solution to an answer

Eclipse Juno SR1 installs m2e plugin version 1.2. The m2e connecter `buildhelper` provided by the Eclipse marketplace is not compatible with this version of the m2e plugin. I've been looking through various mailinglists, but I cannot find a location where to find an updated buildhelper.

The following error occurs when trying to install the m2e connector buildhelper:

```
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109282249 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201109282249)
Software currently installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2.0.20120903-1050     (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.20120903-1050)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.2.0.20120903-1050 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.2.0.20120903-1050)
    Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.1.0.20120530-0009 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.1.0.20120530-0009)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.2.0.20120903-1050 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.20120903-1050)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.2.0.20120903-1050]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109282249 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper 0.15.0.201109282249)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.1.0,1.2.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201109282249 (org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201109282249)
    To: org.sonatype.m2e.buildhelper [0.15.0.201109282249]
```

In our pom files we use buildhelper to add directories with generated sources to the   Eclipse:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
      <!-- Fix this eclipse error by discovering the plugin in the marketplace -->
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: You should put your solution into an answer and mark the question as answered so it is obvious that the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I moved the solution to the answer below. I need to wait two days before I can mark my own answer as the solution.

Comment: Here, adding the lifecycle mapping directly to the pom helped to solve the issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20249944/873282.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The comment in the pom suggested to use the Eclipse marketplace to install the buildhelper:

```
<!-- Fix this eclipse error by discovering the plugin in the marketplace -->
```

This will not do, because the buildhelper version in the Eclipse marketplace is outdated.

Instead of using the Eclipse Marketplace, I installed the buildhelper directly from the Sonatype repository using the Eclipse install new software menu option. The Sonatype repository with the (currently) latest version is here:
https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e-extras/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201206251206/

This fixed my problem.