# How to access the values set in profiles (in pom.xml) via java code

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have a maven project with different profiles set in pom.xml with different values. But I don't know how to access those values set in profile via java code.
For example-

My pom.xml:

```
<profile>
        <id>scaler</id>
        <properties>
            <user>xxxxxxx</user>
            <secret>yyyyyyyy</secret>
            <proxyHost>172.19.17.13</proxyHost>
            <proxyPort>9444</proxyPort>
            <environment>SCALER</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Java code-

```
String serviceurl = "http://"<proxyhost>":<proxyPort>/";
```

In the above java code, i want to use proxy host as 172.19.17.13 & port as 9444 as defined in pom.xml but how to access those values from pom??
I will appreciate your help

Comment: Maven properties are used for compile-time variables, not really for runtime variables. I believe that, in your case, using a properties file would be a better solution.

Comment: Is your pom in source control? Do you want credentials (user/secret) in source control?

Comment: [One approach is described in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2469922/521799)

Answer (score 5):

You should use the maven filtering feature.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Just add a property file in src/main/resources with some placeholders:

```
key=${myvalue}
```

then `myvalue` should be defined as a property in your pom.xml

Be sure to activate the filter on your resources:

```
<resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how the code will access those values? Can you give some example please?

Comment: you can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it depends on maven profile. You can try to use `properties-maven-plugin` (or other solution) like it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/in-java-code-how-to-access-maven-properties-defined-in-pom). Just to write your properties into file and then use it in java code.