# Including application version number from pom.xml to application bundle

Tags: java, maven, build, version

Each `pom.xml` have:

```
<groupId>com.vendor</groupId>
<artifactId>product</artifactId>
<version>1.0.13.0-dev</version>  <!-- THIS FIELD -->
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

`version` piece is useful to bunch with application so user can see and report them.

But I dislike code duplication and look for a way to avoid putting property file with version info to VCS (Git/SVN) because each time I bump version I must commit into two places (`pom.xml` and `version.properties`).

Which way can I make **version** properties from `pom.xml` programmatically available in Java application?

Comment: You can have this information saved to manifest of jar or war file and then make use of it in your application.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion +1. Currently I try to use technique from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144620/reading-properties-file-from-maven-pom-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). In your `version.properties` (should be in the `resources` folder), define a line like `version=${project.version}`. Make sure to turn on filtering for the plugin (all described in detail at the link above) and you should be good to go!

Just run `mvn resources:resources` (or `mvn compile`) and check the generated file.

Comment: I found a code [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime) that no change Maven config.

Answer (score 12):

Found a solution to use the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) to be more elegant.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
       <webResources>
           <resource>
               <targetPath>WEB-INF/views/jsp</targetPath>
               <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/jsp</directory>
               <includes>
                  <include>footer.jsp</include>
               </includes>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
      </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

footer.jsp then had:

```
Application Version: ${project.version}
```

Comment: Nice! Instead of evaluating this from resource file just inline in JSP files! +1

Answer (score 7):

My personal *production* solution below.

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <version>1.0.13.0-dev</version>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
     ...
```

**base.jsp**:

```
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <a href='<c:url value="/"/>'>
     <spring:eval expression="@props.getProperty('version')"/>
   </a>
   <jsp:include page="${contentPage}" />
</body>
</html>
```

**proj.properties**:

```
version=${project.version}
```

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" autowire="byName" >
    <property name="location" value="classpath:proj.properties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:proj.properties"/>
</bean>
```

or just

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:proj.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply configure the [maven-war-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) like the following:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
       <index>true</index>
       <manifest>
         <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
         <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
       </manifest>
       <manifestEntries>
          <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
       </manifestEntries>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Reading information from [manifest.mf can be done using jacabi.](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-manifests/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! +1 I use resource approach as already have Spring `@Value` for one `.property` file.