# Is it possible to generate a text file with the date using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Relatively new to `Maven` and was wondering if there is a way to generate a text file using `Maven` where the date in the file is the date that it was built?

My goal is to create a text file either inside or beside the packaged `WAR` file containing the date it was built.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this one, with properties file,it should work fine :)
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524824/how-can-i-in-a-jsp-page-get-maven-project-version-number

Comment: And use this answer to get a timestamp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228472/how-to-acces-maven-build-timestamp-for-resource-filtering

Comment: @Czarny Thanks, really helped me learn and understand the resources and filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of info would probably best go into the manifest. You can [customize your manifest](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html) easily in Maven.
If you really want a simple file, either generate one using e.g. the [Project properties plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) or [filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) an existing one (in src/main/resources by default). To get the date value, use [this](http://java.dzone.com/tips/stamping-version-number-and).

Comment: What is a `Manifest` and what's its purpose? Couldn't it be simply replaced with a `.property` file?

Comment: Manifests contain various meta-data about the artifact. They're a standard feature in Java and are well documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html
If you want a .properties file, I explained how to generate one and how to include the timestamp.
Please accept my answer if it resolved your question.