# Not able to display the maven project version information in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, maven

I am trying to display the maven version information on my JSP page. I googled on this and found many different solutions for this, some on blog posts and some on stackoverflow out of which most of them are pretty old dating back to 2009. I picked one on stackoverflow ([How can I in a jsp page get maven project version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524824/how-can-i-in-a-jsp-page-get-maven-project-version-number)) and tried to follow it by putting in the following code snippet in my pom and calling ${project.version} in my JSP but it do not work.

Am i missing anything ?

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </webResources>   
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

However, I do not see the version getting displayed. Not sure what I am missing.

**Complete pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ebayenterprise.ecp</groupId>
    <artifactId>JobStatusCollectorWebapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>JobStatusCollectorWebapp</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.5</slf4jVersion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- UI handling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- log4j logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- any library that uses commons-logging will be directed to slf4j -->
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- any library that uses slf4j will be directed to java.util.logging -->
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<!-- Header -->

<!-- Content -->

<!-- Footer -->
<br/><div align="right">Version:${project.version}</div><br/>
```

Comment: can you post your entire pom.xml? Are you sure you're packaging your app into a war?

Comment: The entire pom is already posted up and yes I am packaging into a war

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution?

Mayber you can retrieve this in a code and get it on your jsp.

[Retrieve version from maven pom.xml in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code)

Comment: Please do add some explanation to your answer.