# How to View Output XML file after Maven Build

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have an xml file in my project where I have defined an element like :

`<ver>${project.version}</ver>`

After doing a maven build, how can I view the output xml. I am looking for output like :

`<ver>2.0</ver>`

where project version is `2.0`

Comment: Element <ver>${project.version}</ver> should be displayed as <ver>2.0</ver>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524824/how-can-i-in-a-jsp-page-get-maven-project-version-number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524824/how-can-i-in-a-jsp-page-get-maven-project-version-number)